# Syntax error in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, mips

I'm having a strange problem with an assembly file. Every time I load this file into PCSpim, it gives me a syntax error on line 23. I've looked at several references and asked several classmates for help, and nobody seems to understand what's wrong.

```
.globl main

.data
test1:     .word 92
test2:     .word 81
finalExam: .word 90
a:         .ascii "Enter value A:\n"
b:         .ascii "Enter value B:\n"
grade:     .word 0
result:    .word 0
#More data...

.text
#Program calculates a final grade based off of two midterms and a final. Midterms are
#weighted 30% and the final is weighted 40%. Grade is out of 1000.
final: 
li    $t4, 3 #PCSpim complains here.
li    $t5, 4
la    $t0, test1
lw    $t1, ($t0)
mult  $t1, $t4
mflo  $t1
la    $t0, test2
lw    $t2, ($t0)
mult  $t2, $t4
mflo  $t2
la    $t0, finalExam
lw    $t3, ($t0)
mult  $t3, $t5
mflo  $t3
add   $t4, $t1, $t2
add   $t4, $t4, $t3
la    $t0, grade
sw    $t4, ($t0)
#Print result to console
li    $v0, 1 
move  $a0, $t4
syscall
jr    $ra

#Program continues...
```

Comment: What's the syntax error and which line is line 23?

Comment: Line 23 is the very beginning of the text section (li $t4, 3), and it does not specify what the syntax error is, which is biggest source of my confusion.

Comment: Just to clarify, Pseudo-ops, Bare Machine are enabled and Mapped I/O is disabled.

Comment: Can you provide a reduced example? You may also want to check for invisible characters (carriage returns, nonbreaking spaces, etc.) that may be causing problems.

Comment: You have `.globl main` as you should, but you don't have it defined. Instead you have label `final` at the entry point. I am guessing that's what's confusing pcspim. That's not an excuse for not giving sensible error message, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out, there were two problems in this situation. First, Bare Machine should have been disabled, and another problem came up when I used "b" as a label, because b is also used as an opcode.

Thanks for checking this out!